# Composite indexes in Spring Data Redis

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I'm using spring data Redis, I'm adding functionality to the project to query Redis hash object with multiple fields. I just created secondary indices on those fields using @Indexed annotation from spring data Redis core.
My question is, is there a way to configure my Redis hash object so that I use multi column indexes? Similar to spring data mongo @CompoundIndex.

I can see there's a org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.CompositeIndexResolver.java, but Im not sure if there is a way to configure compound indexes from java using spring data Redis.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple fields marked with `@Indexed`, for example, `field1` and `field2` you can create queries like `findByField1AndField2`, for example. Spring Data Redis keeps a set for each index, so in the case of the `AND` predicate, it uses Redis' `SINTER` command. See what kind of queries are possible here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.queries

There is also Redis OM Spring which uses a real search engine and allows more complex queries and aggregations. See https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring